# I created a new user, and this user is recognized as a root user, how do I return him back to a normal user

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, users, root, sudoedit

I execute a normal command to create a file and it tells me access is denied, after that I use Sudo the file I created belongs to the root user and not to the user I created
whoami returns user1

ls -l to the file i created shows root root and not user1 user1
all the simple command permission denied
i tried to configure sudoers but nothing change

Comment: That's a normal behavior, if you want to create a file with your current user you should use: `touch file` or if you have to use **sudo** then use: `sudo --user=$USER touch file`

Comment: Thank you for your comment , But that's not what I meant .

Comment: I have my main user, I created a new user named user 1 when I change to user 1 and try to create a folder the content of the file is -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov 13 ........

Comment: Instead it should recognize me as user 1 and not as root user

Comment: what like the opposite of this command sudo usermod -aG sudo username

Comment: Regarding your question: *"I execute a normal command to create a file and it tells me access is denied"*, when you change from *main user* to *user 1* you could get **Access denied** message because you don't have the permissions to write/read/execute/delete under the current directory you are.
For example, if you are on `/home/mainuser` (logged as main user) and switch to `user1` and you still are on `/home/mainuser` then you will no be able to do anything under that directory. Hence you should change to another directory to be able to make changes.

Comment: But now, as you said in the comment *" I change to user 1 and try to create a folder..."*, how did you create the folder and where? Did you not get a **Access denied** or **Permission denied** message?

Comment: (1) It’s totally normal for a file that you created with `sudo` to be owned by root.  (2) The body of the question says one thing; the title and the comments say something different.  Please [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete; do not provide essential details in comments. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (3) It seems like you’re new to Unix.  Let me give you some advice: Don’t use `sudo` unless you’re sure you know what you’re doing, or you are carefully following precise and detailed instructions given by somebody knowledgeable.  If you get an “access denied” error message, your first instinct should *not* be to do the same thing, but with `sudo`.  You should understand why access was denied, and think about whether you have a good reason to override the system’s protections.

Comment: Thanks for your responses , I will try my best !